# Spring Application Context issue - Datasource Bean Creation

Tags: spring, jetty

This webapp of mine is working perfectly fine on my localhost jetty server. I'm testing it out on Jelastic so I can fix any issue before deploying to a production server.

Issue is, app can't start because of a misconfiguration that I can't get fixed, can you help me out?

Full stack trace for the issue is:

```
[ERROR] ioc.Registry Operations trace:
[ERROR] ioc.Registry [ 1] Realizing service ApplicationContext
[ERROR] ioc.Registry [ 2] Instantiating service ApplicationContext implementation via ObjectCreator for Spring ApplicationContext
[ERROR] ioc.Registry [ 3] Creating Spring ApplicationContext via ContextLoader
[ERROR] SpringModuleDef.ApplicationContext Construction of service ApplicationContext failed: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException; remaining name 'jdbc/appDB'
org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException; remaining name 'jdbc/appDB'
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.logAndRethrow(OperationTrackerImpl.java:121)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:88)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:87)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1124)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.spring.SpringModuleDef$3.createObject(SpringModuleDef.java:184)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackingObjectCreator$1.invoke(OperationTrackingObjectCreator.java:45)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:74)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:87)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1124)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackingObjectCreator.createObject(OperationTrackingObjectCreator.java:49)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.SingletonServiceLifecycle.createService(SingletonServiceLifecycle.java:29)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.LifecycleWrappedServiceCreator.createObject(LifecycleWrappedServiceCreator.java:46)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.AdvisorStackBuilder.createObject(AdvisorStackBuilder.java:63)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.InterceptorStackBuilder.createObject(InterceptorStackBuilder.java:54)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RecursiveServiceCreationCheckWrapper.createObject(RecursiveServiceCreationCheckWrapper.java:60)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackingObjectCreator$1.invoke(OperationTrackingObjectCreator.java:45)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:74)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:87)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1124)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackingObjectCreator.createObject(OperationTrackingObjectCreator.java:49)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.services.JustInTimeObjectCreator.obtainObjectFromCreator(JustInTimeObjectCreator.java:66)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.services.JustInTimeObjectCreator.createObject(JustInTimeObjectCreator.java:54)
    at $ConfigurableWebApplicationContext_38b45053c6a2.delegate(Unknown Source)
    at $ConfigurableWebApplicationContext_38b45053c6a2.getBeanDefinitionCount(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.spring.SpringModule$1.initializeApplication(SpringModule.java:61)
    at $ApplicationInitializer_38b45053c6be.initializeApplication(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$40.initializeApplication(TapestryModule.java:2438)
    at $ApplicationInitializer_38b45053c6be.initializeApplication(Unknown Source)
    at $ApplicationInitializer_38b45053c6ba.initializeApplication(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$ServletApplicationInitializerTerminator.initializeApplication(TapestryModule.java:279)
    at $ServletApplicationInitializer_38b45053c69f.initializeApplication(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.TapestryFilter.init(TapestryFilter.java:116)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:713)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1282)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:518)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:499)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:985)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:194)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:534)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:441)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.main(Main.java:119)
```

It seeems to be a problem with `/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml`, right? Let's check it out.

**/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
  xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<!-- Enable the Spring MVC stuff -->
<mvc:annotation-driven/>

  <!-- Enable usage of @Autowired. -->
  <context:annotation-config/>

  <!-- Enable component scanning for defining beans with annotations. -->
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.viktortech.automaton.model"/>

  <!--  For translating native persistence exceptions to Spring's 
        DataAccessException hierarchy. -->
<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

<bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
    <property name="environment">
        <props>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">org.mortbay.naming.InitialContextFactory</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">org.mortbay.naming</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">

    <property name="jndiTemplate">
      <ref bean="jndiTemplate"/>
    </property>
    <property name="jndiName">
          <value>jdbc/appDB</value>
    </property>
  </bean>


<!-- ***********************************************************************
     To avoid requesting unnecessary connections (not necessary for
     MiniBank) with the Open Session in View filter, uncomment this and
     change "sessionFactory" bean (bellow) to use "dataSourceProxy" instead
     of "dataSource".
<bean id="dataSourceProxy" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy"
    p:targetDataSource-ref="dataSource"/>
     ******************************************************************* -->

<!-- Hibernate Session Factory -->
  <bean id="sessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
      p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
      p:configLocation="classpath:/automaton-hibernate-config.xml"/>

  <!-- Transaction manager for a single Hibernate SessionFactory.  -->
  <bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"
      p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />

<!-- Enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on
     annotations. -->
  <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

  <bean id="manageService"
    class="com.viktortech.automaton.model.manageservice.ManageServiceImpl"/>

<bean id="botService"
    class="com.viktortech.automaton.model.botservice.BotServiceImpl"/>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.viktortech.automaton.rest" />

</beans>
```

So what's this JNDI jdbc/appDB, where it's defined and how? Right away, it's in the `/WEB-INF/jetty-env.xml` file

```
<Configure class="org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">

    <New id="viktor" class="org.mortbay.jetty.plus.naming.Resource">
        <Arg>jdbc/appDB</Arg>
        <Arg>
            <New class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
                <Set name="driverClassName">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</Set>
                <Set name="url">jdbc:mysql://workingDBserver/database</Set>
                <Set name="username">******</Set>
                <Set name="password">******</Set>
            </New>
        </Arg>
   </New>
</Configure>
```

So that's it. As I said, it runs pretty smooth on localhost:8080, but when deploying to a remote jetty server (Same jetty version) it goes 503 and then produces that error stated above.

Please, please, ask for any other resource you need to fix this out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Creating "datasource" bean is a problem. "sessionFactory" bean will be created if datasource bean creation is successful. Since you are saying that it gives you 503 error, probably the service to database is down/ it doesnt have access. Are you sure that your application on remote server can connect to the database.

Comment: 100% sure, since the DB server is not located in localhost. I'm sure it can be accessed remotely and all that stuff (already tested)

Comment: Could it be that the datasource id in jetty-env.xml is 'viktor' and not 'appDB'? It shouldn't change anything for JNDI but...

Comment: Looks like its a jar issue. The exception is thrown when creating bean "jndiTemplate" and setting its properties. Can you check the jar conatining "org.mortbay.naming.InitialContextFactory" is being loaded in the server environment.

Comment: Note: `org.mortbay` is a sign that you are using Jetty 6.  Jetty 6 was EOL'd in 2010, and cannot be considered safe for production use today. (ok for intranet and other isolated networks).  Consider upgrading (Jetty 9 is current)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a missing library on the classpath?

```
Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mortbay.naming.InitialContextFactory
```

Are you using Maven?  How are you getting all the jars needed for the application loaded into your classpath in the JVM that's trying to run this application?

Comment: I'm using Maven indeed, but for deploying I'm just uploading my .war to the server. Should I set up maven in my server and deploy there via mvn install or something? If so, could you give me some advice on that? I'm a first-timer for all of these things.

Comment: You can extract the war and see if the library folder has the requried jar. Further you can extract the jar and check if the class definition is there or not. If the .class file exists, then the last thing I will check is if its in the classpath and is being loaded by the classloader.

Comment: Completing Edwin R Rivera's answer, yes, the issue was the classpath wasn't built, so the JARs weren't being loaded properly into the server. There was also a JNDI naming issue. Fixed both of those is not stacktracing anymore, having other issues (SSL related), but this one is fixed